# Hide/show a tag <Text> based on service/ dynamically from json in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, reactive-programming, react-native-ios

The below is my JSON,

```
"[{"id":32156465,"b_name":"KFC","website":"kfc.com","category":[]},{"id":87985645,"b_name":"Pizza Hut","website":"pizzahut.com","category":[{"id":"357","title":"Pizza"}]},{"id":78956465,"b_name":"Mc Donalds","website":"mcdonalds.com","category":[{"id":"951","title":"Burger"}]},{"id":32136556,"b_name":"Eagle Boys Pizza","website":null,"category":[]}]"
```

Need to iterate category array, if there are any objects present, then I need to get the title and display as:

```
Category: Testing
```

else the "Category:" text should not be shown.

This is what my whole code is that i have tried

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { showCategoryList: false }
      }

      categoriesList(categoriesObject) {
        var categoriesListStr = ""
        categoriesObject.map((categoryDict) => {
          Object.keys(categoryDict).map(function (key, value) {
            console.log("Key- " + key + "Value-" + value)
            if ((key == "title") && (categoryDict[key] !== null)) {
              categoriesListStr = categoryDict[key]
            }
          })
        })
        return categoriesListStr
      }

      _renderItem = ({ item, section }) => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.rowViewContainer1}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 12, fontWeight: "normal", marginLeft: 10}}>{'Business Name: ' + item.b_name}</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 12, fontWeight: "normal", marginLeft: 10}}>{'Website: ' + item.website}</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 12, fontWeight: "normal", marginLeft: 10}}>{'Category: ' + this.categoriesList(item.category)}</Text>
            {/* here, if categoriesListStr returns empty string, then we should not display"Category: ", how can i achieve this */}
            <View style={styles.lineViewSeparation} />
          </View>
        )
      };

      _renderSectionHeader = ({ section }) => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.sectionHeader}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>{section.key}</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
      render() {
        var prospectsDataArr = [{"id":32156465,"b_name":"KFC","website":"kfc.com","category":[]},{"id":87985645,"b_name":"Pizza Hut","website":"pizzahut.com","category":[{"id":"357","title":"Pizza"}]},{"id":78956465,"b_name":"Mc Donalds","website":"mcdonalds.com","category":[{"id":"951","title":"Burger"}]},{"id":32136556,"b_name":"Eagle Boys Pizza","website":null,"category":[]}]
        var prospectsDict = { key: 'New', data: prospectsDataArr }
        dataSourceArr = [prospectsDict]
        console.log("renderedItem " + this._renderItem)
        return (
          <View style={{ marginTop: (Platform.OS) == 'ios' ? 20 : 0 }}>
            <SectionList style={styles.cellView}
              sections={dataSourceArr}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}
              renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Here, if categoriesListStr returns empty string, then we should not display"Category: ", how can i achieve this

Comment: is the json structure changing? i am not understanding why are you getting object keys for?

Comment: No the structure is not changing

Comment: Welcome. Your can improve your question to get a chance to receive more useful answers, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following:

```
<Text> 
  {'Category: ' + this.categoriesList(item.category)}
</Text>
```

With this:

```
{
item.category.length > 0 && <Text>{'Category: ' + this.categoriesList(item.category)}</Text>
}
```

**Additional Note:**

Your `categoriesList` function returns only one category title. If you are going to have max. of only one object in `category` array or you are fine with returning any one of the titles, then you may not need `categoriesList` function and you can just use

`{'Category: ' + item.category[0].title}`

to return the first title (if found) in place of

`{'Category: ' + this.categoriesList(item.category)}</Text>}`

Comment: Thank you @xuhaib, this is great help, there will be some more categories in the list, now I can form string.

Comment: @iOSDev does that answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

if this.state.names is an array then you can iterate over names array and display each element title value in the array.

```
render() {
  return Array.isArray(this.state.names) ? this.state.names.map(el => {
    return (
      <Text>Name : {el.title}</Text>
    )
  }) : <Text>No Data</Text>
}
```